# Passing data from page to page c# windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

What i am trying to do is pass the Total amount from the checkout page to the summary page. The total amount works on the checkout page but when i try to pass with this code : `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Summary), new { TotalValue });` , it does nothing. 
Here is the code i put to give me the Total amount on the checkout page

```
  private double totalValue;

            public double TotalValue
            {
                get { return totalValue; }
                set
                {
                    totalValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
                }
            }

        public IEnumerable<Control> Controls { get; private set; }

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            BuyingPage.Flavour data = e.Parameter as BuyingPage.Flavour;
            /**    ItemChosentxt.Text = data.Name;
                ItemChosentxt2.Text = data.Name;
                ItemChosentxt3.Text = data.Name;
                ItemChosentxt4.Text = data.Name;**/
            if (data != null)
            {   
                Flavour.Add(data);
                double tempTotalValue = 0;
                foreach (var record in Flavour)
                {
                    tempTotalValue = tempTotalValue + record.Value;
                }
                TotalValue = tempTotalValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `e.Parameter` to `BuyingPage.Flavour` but passing it like an anonymous type: `new { TotalValue }`.

Either create a new instance of `BuyingPage.Flavour` and pass it like `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Summary), flavor);` or change the following line:

```
BuyingPage.Flavour data = e.Parameter as BuyingPage.Flavour;
```

to something like:

```
dynamic data = e.Parameter;
```

Or, making it simpler, like suggested by @Archana:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Summary), TotalValue);
```

and then:

```
double data = (double)e.Parameter;
```

Comment: That is not a `dynamic` type, but an anonymous.

Comment: Why does that matter? My question is not about that. That part works. I am talking about getting the total value that is displayed on the checkout page to show on the summary page also

Comment: Why are you doing this " new { TotalValue }"? TotalValue is of type double right?

Comment: If you want just total value to be passed do like thisFrame.Navigate(typeof(Summary),TotalValue);

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev You're right! Just editted the answer. But, anyway, to access the `TotalValue` property we have to use `dynamic`, right, or is there another way?